# Eigenvalues of the principal submatrix of a Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, faq

This question aims at creating an "[abstract duplicate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1756/18880)" of various questions that can be reduced to the following:

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix and $B$ be an $r\times r$ principal submatrix of $A$. How are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ related?

Here are some questions on this site that can be viewed as duplicates of this question:

- [Eigenvalues of $MA$ versus eigenvalues of $A$ for orthogonal projection $M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653611/eigenvalues-of-ma-versus-eigenvalues-of-a-for-orthogonal-projection-m)
- [Relationship of eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix D and $\mathbf{VDV}^{T}$, where V is a semi-orthogonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669567/relationship-of-eigenvalues-of-a-diagonal-matrix-d-and-mathbfvdvt-where)

Answer (score 14):

> **Proposition.** Let $\lambda_k(\cdot)$ denotes the $k$-th smallest eigenvalue of a Hermitian matrix. Then
>   $$
> \lambda_k(A)\le\lambda_k(B)\le\lambda_{k+n-r}(A),\quad 1\le k\le r.
> $$

This is a well-known result in linear algebra. Since the usual proof is just a straightforward application of the celebrated [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem), we shall not repeat it here. See, e.g. theorem 4.3.15 (p.189) of Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, 1/e, Cambridge University Press, 1985.

Comment: They gave the _Matrix Analysis_ book the volume number $\exp(-1)\approx0.3679$? How cute!

Comment: Just thought of adding a link to the answer, in case someone is looking at editiopns 2e or 3e:

http://www.cse.zju.edu.cn/eclass/attachments/2015-10/01-1446086008-145421.pdf, see P. 4.3.28.

Comment: I am looking for a similar result for not necessarily symetric or Hermitian matrices. I tried to follow the cited proof (as well as thm. 4.3.28 in the second edition) but could not find a point in the proof where it strictly needs the Hermitian property. Where does it fail? Are there similar results?